# jquery ready handler never executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website about festivals, with a separate page for each festival. Normally, a festival's page should look something [like this](http://www.festivals.ie/festival/show/1), but [one of the festival pages](http://www.festivals.ie/festival/show/30) has a few problems. These include:

- twitter and facebook buttons in header don't load
- google map in top-right corner doesn't load
- festival lineup is not laid out properly and blue background thereof doesn't appear

After some debugging, I discovered that this is because the jQuery ready handler is not being executed. The handler I'm referring to is in an linine script that begins on line 3252 of the page.

I guess the reason this doesn't get executed is because a JavaScript error occurs earlier on in the page-loading process, but I can't see any evidence of errors in Firebug.

Comment: '...in an linine script that begins on line 3252...'  Seriously?

Comment: @JohnGreen-PageSpike in my defence, a lot of those lines are blank, probably only about 1500 non-blank lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the code, I see the following at line 2673:

```
<div id="video"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/A71ID1Hlw70" frameborder="0" ahttp://www.festivals.ie/festival/edit/30#llowfullscreen></iframhttp://www.festivals.ie/festival/edit/30#e>
```

Thanks to Chrome's automatic syntax highlighting (and breaking thereof at 2673) for identifying this unclosed iframe.